# массовая замена текста в текстовых файлах

Tags: python, python-3.x, notepad++

есть папка text
внутри нее лежат текстовые файлы с содержанием типа :

```
Москва/А/1-1каб
Москва/А/2-1каб
```

с помощью notepad++ есть функция Find in Files
которая ищет в файлах нужный текст и заменяет его
я почти добился желаемого результата

```
Москва/А/1 этаж 
Москва/А/2 этаж
```

Но проблема в том что notepad ++ только заменяет текст и оставляет то что было
тоесть если я меняю так - Москва/А/1 заменить на Москва/А/1 этаж, он сделает Москва/А/1 этаж-1каб
есть вариант в notepad++ или другой программой массово отсечь до конца строки по параметру? чтобы дальше 1 этаж, не было символов в строке

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я верно понял, то в N++ сделайте в замене:

`Москва/А/1.*` на `Москва/А/1 этаж`

не забудьте поставить галку "Регуляр. выражен."

Comment: если ответ решает ваш вопрос не забудьте отметить его решением, это поможет другим пользователям